# jQuery: Scrolling div section wise

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a error panel on top of the page which I want to control it's scrolling.
How can I scroll it section wise if possible? 
So when user scrolls vertically error panel should move one section to another.

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/himanshuy/cgj87/).
Panel code is

```
<div class="panel-group" id="errors">
        <div class="panel panel-danger">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
              <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
                Error(s)
              </a>
            </h4>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" style="height: 0px;">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="active">
                            <th>Error Message</th>
                            <th>Error Code</th>
                            <th>Results</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>              
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to wrap a scrolling container around the section divs. Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wmk4Q/

```
.scroller {
    height: 150px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```